# Processing rows with optional separator

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have to process a file which has a set of rows in following format:

```
{name:value}
```

- The Name can have a `:` which is escaped using `\`.
- The `:` is optional in which case only name needs to be read.
- If `:` is not there then value is missing. The value can also contain `}` which is escaped using `\`.

So, valid values are:

```
{john:nice person}
{john}
```

I used this regex:

```
{(?<name>.*?(?=(?<!\\)\:))(?<separator>:?)(?<value>.*?(?=(?<!\\)\}))}
```

which works for the first format but fails if the format is {name} without the separator and value.  Any ideas how can I modify the regex to read both formats?

Comment: Can the value be present, but empty, as `{john:}`?

Answer (score 0):

[Try](https://regexr.com/49ems) `\{(?<name>(?:[^:}]|\\:)+)(?:(?<!\\):(?<value>(?:[^}]|\\\})+))?(?<!\\)\}`

I grouped the *separator* and the *value* together into an optional group `(?:)?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\{((?:[^\n:]|(?<=\\):)+)(?::((?:[^:\n}]|(?<=\\)})+))?}
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/f7goQZKUi3j7ZD).